# How to check if one module is already opened in a Perl/Tk application

Tags: perl, perl-module, perltk

In a [`Perl/Tk`](https://metacpan.org/module/SREZIC/Tk-804.030/Tk.pod) `MainWindow`, in the menu bar, if I click on an option, then I can open same module twice, thrice etc. But if it is already opened, then it should not open again. Any idea how to do that?

```
$mw = MainWindow->new;
$mw->configure(-menu =>  $menubar = $mw->Menu);
$bikes=$menubar->cascade(-label => '~Bikes');
$cars = $menubar->cascade(-label => '~Cars');


$cars->command(-label => 'Honda', -command=>\&honda_cars);
$cars->command(-label => 'Chevrolet',-command=>\&Chevrolet_cars);

$bikes->command(-label => 'Honda', -command=>\&honda_bikes);
$bikes->command(-label => 'Bajaj', -command=>\&bajaj_bikes);
```

Now if I click on Chevrolet then I can get the same window again whenever I click the option the in menu bar. I want to check if it is already opened, then it should not open again.

Comment: Set a variable to 1 on opening the window, set it to zero on closing. Do not open the window if its variable is set to 1.

Answer (score 1):

You need a variable, set by the `Chevrolet_cars` subroutine etc. that says whether that page is already open.

You don't say anything about the way your application works, but it may be possible to detect whether the element is currently displayed without using a flag variable.